# Using limits to prove asymptotic bounds

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I hope this is the right place to ask this question.

I'm reading Cormen Introduction to algorithms for a class and sometimes the formulas are a little overwhelming.

For instance:

[image]

What does this have to do with limits?  He mentions limits in regard to little o, but not for `Θ` or `Ω`.

How can I prove using limits that a function is in another function's Omega or Theta?

If `F(n) = 5n² + 3` and `G(n) = 35n + 7` is `F` in `Ω(G)` or G in `Θ(F)`?

Comment: You should try posting that question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for  math.stackexchange.com

Comment: "Limit" in the mathematical sense isn't directly involved here, do you mean "bound"? That definition of theta says that any *f(n)* that is in *theta(g(n))* is always bounded above by *g(n)* times some constant *c2* and below by *g(n)* times some constant *c1* (once *n* is greater than some *n0*).

Answer (score 2):

The Definition says, that `f` is in `Θ(g)`, if you can find two constants `c₁` and `c₂` and an input size `n₀` such that `c₁⋅g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c₂⋅g(n)` holds for all `n ≥ n₀`.

You can use limits to show that such constants exist, which is why you can define `o`, `O`, `Θ`, `Ω` and `ω` with limits, instead of the definition above.

In your example:

```
limn → ∞ | F(n) / G(n) | = limn → ∞ | (5n² + 3) / (35n + 7) | = ∞
```

This shows that `F` grows faster than `G` and you cannot find a constant `c` and a fixed `n₀` such that `F(n) ≤ c⋅ G(n)` holds for all `n > n₀`. So `F` is not in `O(G)` and thus also not in `Θ(G)`. In fact this indicates that `F` is in `ω(G)` and so its also in `Ω(G)`, or (if you like it the other way around better) `G` is in `o(F)`.

You can see this, by applying the condition with the constants into the limit.

Notice: There are many possible ways to pick the constants and `n₀`. The Limits does not get you this constants, but only shows if they exist or not.